# replacing values of a matrix with an if operation using matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, cell

```
mn = 1 
for kn = 1:199 
  for sn = 1:19773 
      if abs((x1c{kn+1,1}(sn)) - (x1c{kn,1}(sn))) >= 20 
          extract{mn} = x1c{kn+1,1}(sn); 
          mn = mn+1;
      end
   end
end
extend = cell2mat(extract) + 40;
```

How can I change the values of "x1c" with the values of "extend"?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the values"? Please fix your indentation, it's making my eyes bleed.

Comment: I want to change the particular elements of "x1c" cell which has been extracted with respect to a if operation, with the values of "extend". It is maybe the time to "change the eyeglasses".

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Do you want to assign the contents of `extend` to `x1c`? Which particular elements?

Comment: There is a if operation there; some elements of "x1c" abide by this operation. Later, I want the add 40 into these elements, and put them inside the cell; i.e. replacing the "extract" with the "extend".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing the operation on a cell. Considering you're comparing numbers, this would be done far more efficiently when done with matrices.

I therefor suggest you convert the cell (or a subset of it) to a matrix and then use vectorized operations, like this:

```
>> a={[13, 2, 3], [14, 25, 8], [100, 9, 10], [101, 8, 32], [140, 20, 3]};
>> 
>> x = transpose(reshape(cell2mat(a), 3, []));
>> z = abs(x(2:end, :) - x(1:end-1,:)) > 20;
>> z2 = [zeros(1,3); z]

z2 =

     0     0     0
     0     1     0
     1     0     0
     0     0     1
     1     0     1

>> x(logical(z2)) = x(logical(z2)) - 200

x =

    13     2     3
    14  -175     8
  -100     9    10
   101     8  -168
   -60    20  -197
```

There are two alternatives if you really must use cells (I don't recommend it for speed reasons).

1. *store the indices* (`k, sn`) of the cell items where your condition holds true. And then you'd have to loop over the elements again (very inefficient).
2. You'd store the previous and next cell "row" in temporary variables and compare using those. When the condition holds, edit in-place and take the temporary variable with you in the next iteration of the loop. The code below shows how this is done:

   ```
   a={[13, 2, 3], [14, 25, 8], [100, 9, 10], [101, 8, 32], [140, 20, 3]};

   curr_row = a{1};
   for rowind=1:4
       next_row = a{rowind+1};
       for colind=1:3
           if abs(next_row(1, colind) - curr_row(1, colind)) > 20
               a{rowind+1}(1, colind) = a{rowind+1}(1, colind) + 40;
           end
       end
       curr_row = next_row;
   end
   ```